# resizing width / height properties of fabricjs Rects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js to define rectangular areas that can be resized. I was wondering if there is any way to set up fabric so that it would resize the element with changing the width / height properties instead of scaleX and scaleY?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `object:scaling` event.

```
canvas.on("object:scaling", function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!target || target.type !== 'rect') {
        return;
    }
    var sX = target.scaleX;
    var sY = target.scaleY;
    target.width *= sX;
    target.height *= sY;
    target.scaleX = 1;
    target.scaleY = 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The fact that width and height doesn't change when you resize the object in fabric.js is so counterintuitive!

Comment: because you think you are resizing, but you are scaling. There is written no where that there is a resize event, just scaling.

Comment: When using this, draw a rect, and then scale it with the center left side handle. drag back and forth, and you'll notice that the right side moves when it shouldn't. You can also get strange behavior by dragging one edge of the rect all the way to the other edge.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi - pinging you here too

Comment: Check this out. If you click/drag the right middle handle back and forth, all is good. do the same with the left middle handle, and you'll see the right side move.

https://codepen.io/carter485/pen/eLbayb

Comment: As the other answer says, you need to `target.dirty = true;` otherwise the shape doesn't visually update - only the resize handles update.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the dirty flag, that fixed most of the issues for me:

```
canvas.on("object:scaling", function (e) {
            var target = e.target;
            if (!target || target.type !== 'rect') {
                return;
            }
            var sX = target.scaleX;
            var sY = target.scaleY;
            target.width *= sX;
            target.height *= sY;
            target.scaleX = 1;
            target.scaleY = 1;
            target.dirty = true;
        });
```